# Ubuntu on a Fresh Lenovo G400

Tags: boot, usb, lenovo

I downloaded 12.04 using OS X, transferred the ISO to USB, then set the Lenovo G400 to boot from USB. However, it just goes back to FreeDOS and nothing happens. What else should I do?

Thanks

Comment: How did you transfer the iso to USB? You do not have to simply copy the file but create a bootable disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your USB is not bootable. If you search on the web you will find many source to know how to do so.

If you must do it in OS X, this is the official guide be ubuntu: [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)